# how can i solve input not suported on second screen to connect to the laptop?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, resolution, external-display

i am having old aoc monitor (very old) i want to connect it to the laptop win 10
i use hdmi to vga converter and connected it to the laptop
after that the monitor showing the message that "input not supported"
when i change the option in multiple display to the only show on screen 2(monitor )
then only monitor displaying the laptop screen and laptop screen get off
i have updated all the drivers
i am unable to extend the screen or duplicate the screen
in laptop display setings it also showing that didn't detect another display
please help me ......
thank u

Comment: Do you mean HDMI to VGA converter? I'm guessing your old AOC has VGA. Please check your adapter and confirm you have the right onw.

Comment: yes sry  by mistake i am using hdmi to vga converter and myaoc is having vga pin

Comment: Then please use the EDIT button to correct your question.

Comment: The HDMI to VGA converter probably has it's own resolution settings on the device itself (like buttons).  You need to ensure the PC is outputting an HDMI resolution the the converter can recognize, and the converter is outputting a VGA resolution that your AOC monitor can recognize.

Comment: thank u but converter is not having any type of keys we have to only connect wires to it

Answer (score 0):

The display-resolution of the laptop is too high for the old monitor.
The HDMI-VGA converter is just a dumb converter. It is the laptops display-settings that determine the resolution send to the display.
You will have to lower the laptop resolution before you try to send the image to the monitor.

Set your laptop to clone its display to the external monitor so you can see what you are doing on the LCD screen of the laptop.
Start with the lowest resolution you can set on the laptop and then go higher step by step until you find the  highest resolution the monitor can accept.

Please note: It is possible that the lowest on the laptop is already too much for the monitor. It is also possible that the HDMI-VGA converter can't go low enough. In both cases you will not be able to find a working solution. The monitor is just too old.